# mediaelement.js - multiple videos on one page - > end and show poster when you start another one

Tags: javascript, html5-video, mediaelement.js, mediaelement

I have multiple videos on a site (mediaelement.js)

When i play one, all others pause and end which is fine.

But i want to show also the poster again.

How can i do it?

for now i modified the pauseOtherPlayers (function) to set the time back to 0 but i want the poster to show not only the beginning.

```
        // FOCUS: when a video starts playing, it takes focus from other players (possibily pausing them)
            media.addEventListener('play', function() {
                var playerIndex;

                // go through all other players
                for (playerIndex in mejs.players) {
                    var p = mejs.players[playerIndex];
                    if (p.id != t.id && t.options.pauseOtherPlayers && !p.paused && !p.ended) {
                         p.pause();
                        p.setCurrentTime(0);



                    }
                    p.hasFocus = false;
                }

                t.hasFocus = true;
            },false);
```

Whats the function to show the poster?

poster.show();  somehow does not work

thx

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

ok figured it out myself.

heres the code if anyone interested:

```
  success:  function (mediaElement, domObject) { 
        mediaElement.addEventListener("pause", function(e){ 
            // Revert to the poster image when ended
            var $thisMediaElement = (mediaElement.id) ? jQuery("#"+mediaElement.id) : jQuery(mediaElement);
            $thisMediaElement.parents(".mejs-inner").find(".mejs-poster").show();
        });

  }
```

Comment: You should post your findings as an answer (it's OK to answer your own questions) and accept it. I wouldn't mind to up vote it ;)